# Mesh on Mesh Clipping

Tags: mesh, clipping

Morning

I have a mesh on top of another mesh and if I make the thickness too low the image clips.

Why and what can I do to avoid it.

[image]

Comment: you can either increase the thickness or move some vertices so that the faces don't overlap?

Comment: I neglected to add that if I increase the thickness the problem is resolved. 

I am worried that I did something wrong on the lower mesh

Comment: I'm not sure why it bothers you, what we see is just vertices going through the faces, what you can try, if you don't want to give it more thickness, is enable the Snap to faces option and move the mesh so that its vertices stick to the faces underneath. You can also try a Shrinkwrap modifier

Comment: Thank you. I am learning so I want to try and understand as much as I can while moving forward.